# Simple android app + database: what do I need in my android application? (PostgreSQL, REST API)

Tags: android, postgresql, rest, heroku

I'm creating a simple android app that hands out rewards depending on the reward points a user has.
Each person should have his own username, password, reward points and wishlisted items etc.

I'm planning to use a PostgreSQL database on Heroku, and writing an REST API on Heroku.

Now I'm not really sure what I need in my ANDROID APPLICATION itself? (apart from the code)

1) Do I need another REST API?

2) Do I need another database?

3) How does my Android application communicate with the REST API (which communicates with the PostgreSQL on Heroku)? -> what java code do I need to write for this?

Thanks so much.
Total beginner who is having a hard time finding proper resources. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1) Do I need another REST API?

You only need one API which will act as the front door to your data.

> 2) Do I need another database?

No you don't *need* another database. If you find the use of local storage a requirement then you can begin looking at making use of a SQLite instance or storing to an SD card where applicable, preferences could be an option as well.

> 3) How does my Android application communicate with the REST API
>   (which communicates with the PostgreSQL on Heroku)? -> what java code
>   do I need to write for this?

You can make use of the `HttpClient` to make a call to the service once it is created. There are many examples on the web, one such example can be found [here](http://lukencode.com/2010/04/27/calling-web-services-in-android-using-httpclient/). Once you interact with your API, it will subsequently make calls to the database via a DAL or other abstraction layer and return the requested data.

```
public class RestClient {

    private ArrayList <NameValuePair> params;
    private ArrayList <NameValuePair> headers;

    private String url;

    private int responseCode;
    private String message;

    private String response;

    public String getResponse() {
        return response;
    }

    public String getErrorMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public int getResponseCode() {
        return responseCode;
    }

    public RestClient(String url)
    {
        this.url = url;
        params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        headers = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    }

    public void AddParam(String name, String value)
    {
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(name, value));
    }

    public void AddHeader(String name, String value)
    {
        headers.add(new BasicNameValuePair(name, value));
    }

    public void Execute(RequestMethod method) throws Exception
    {
        switch(method) {
            case GET:
            {
                //add parameters
                String combinedParams = "";
                if(!params.isEmpty()){
                    combinedParams += "?";
                    for(NameValuePair p : params)
                    {
                        String paramString = p.getName() + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(p.getValue(),”UTF-8″);
                        if(combinedParams.length() > 1)
                        {
                            combinedParams  +=  "&" + paramString;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            combinedParams += paramString;
                        }
                    }
                }

                HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url + combinedParams);

                //add headers
                for(NameValuePair h : headers)
                {
                    request.addHeader(h.getName(), h.getValue());
                }

                executeRequest(request, url);
                break;
            }
            case POST:
            {
                HttpPost request = new HttpPost(url);

                //add headers
                for(NameValuePair h : headers)
                {
                    request.addHeader(h.getName(), h.getValue());
                }

                if(!params.isEmpty()){
                    request.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params, HTTP.UTF_8));
                }

                executeRequest(request, url);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    private void executeRequest(HttpUriRequest request, String url)
    {
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

        HttpResponse httpResponse;

        try {
            httpResponse = client.execute(request);
            responseCode = httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            message = httpResponse.getStatusLine().getReasonPhrase();

            HttpEntity entity = httpResponse.getEntity();

            if (entity != null) {

                InputStream instream = entity.getContent();
                response = convertStreamToString(instream);

                // Closing the input stream will trigger connection release
                instream.close();
            }

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e)  {
            client.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            client.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        String line = null;
        try {
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                is.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks so much Aaron! It was just what I was missing.